# Why Is There a ':' In All Examples of Python's format's mini-language?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I was looking at this specific example:

```
x = 3.45678
print({':.2f'}.format(x))
```

And I cannot for the life of me find any documentation referring to the colon.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-precision

I really prefer if someone could point out where I could've learned this on my own.

Comment: @Phorce In this case it is not slicing

Comment: @Haidro Sorry, my bad. I'm just learning Python and it's the only instance I've seen it

Comment: @Phorce Ah, that's okay :)

Comment: Your syntax is back-to-front; the quotes go *around* the curly braces, not the other way around.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong part of the grammar. See the [`replacement_field`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in the document you mentioned but under [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

> The field_name is optionally followed by a conversion field, which is preceded by an exclamation point '!', and a format_spec, which is preceded by a colon ':'. These specify a non-default format for the replacement value.

Answer (score 2):

the : just sperates the index from the format

it is sometimes implicit (python 2.7+)

```
"{:.2f}  {:d}".format(0.0,1)  == "{0:.2f} , {1:d}".format(0.0,1)
#first   #second
#you could do
"{0:0.2f} {0:0.3f} {1:d}".format(0.0,1)
#or
"{apples:d} {oranges:d}".format(apples=5,oranges=7)
```

Comment: That's true, but the OP was asking how to find the documentation that confirms it, so I think RyPeck's answer is what he really wants.

Comment: The index can be implicit from Python 2.7 onwards.